# Check to see if a product has been purchased - Expresso

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Is there any way in expresso to check if the current user has purchased a particular product?

Something like, `{if purchased}you own this{if:else}you don't own this{/if}`

Thanks

Comment: I also need this functionality

Answer (score 1):

You will need [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash) to get this working

**Setting the stash**

`{if logged_in}
    {exp:store:orders member_id="CURRENT_USER" paid="yes"}
      {if is_order_paid}
        {exp:stash:append name="verify_product" trim="yes"}
          {items}{entry_id}|{/items}
        {/exp:stash:append}
      {/if}
    {/exp:store:orders}
  {/if}`

**Output the variables**

Wrap `exp:channel:entries` loop with `{exp:stash:parse process="end"}{/exp:stash:parse}`

Inside the entries loop

`{if "{exp:stash:verify_product}" ~ "/{entry_id}\b/"}
  You have already brought this map
{if:else}
  {exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}" return="{current_path}"}
    {if qty_in_cart}
      This product is already in your cart.
    {if:else}
      {price} <input type="text" name="item_qty" value="1" /> <button type="submit">Add to cart</button> <button type="submit">Add to cart</button>
    {/if}
  {/exp:store:product}
{/if}`

**Disclamer**: You will need latest version of EE to use the [Matches operator](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#matches-operator) conditional

Comment: Thanks for your answer... I no longer work for the company that was building the site so.. yup... thanks anyway, good to know for any future projects.

Comment: Cheers, leaving it here for reference :)